# What is the value of $a + b + s + t$

Tags: constants

I'm confused as to how to approach this. I've tried to foil it out.

> $$x^3(3x-1)=a+bx+sx^2+tx^3$$ The equation above is true for all values of $x$, where $a$, $b$, $s$, and $t$ are constants. What is the value of $a+b+s+t$?

Answer (score 5):

**hint**: let $x = 1$ in the equation.

Comment: holy crap im an idiot. thank you @BRICKS-Fan

Comment: Without the insight, one could note that $x^2(3x-1)=3x^3-x^2$.

Comment: ... or even note that the $x^2$ multiplier isn't going  to change the result...